# Change words on tkinter Messagebox buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

I'm using tkinter's "askokcancel" message box to warn the user, with a pop-up, of an irreversible action.

```
from tkinter import Tk
Tk().withdraw()
from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel
askokcancel("Warning", "This will delete stuff")
```

I'd like to change the text of the 'OK' button (from 'OK') to something like 'Delete', to make it less benign-looking.

Is this possible?

If not, what is another way to achieve it? Preferably without introducing any dependancies...

Comment: It may be possible but I would not suggest it. Why not using SimpleDialog?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: @Johnny: I actually prematurely discarted tkinter.simpledialog because it looked less flexible than messagebox. Is it possible to overwrite button texts with simpledialog?

Comment: It's not possible because there is no option to change the "ok" text but if you modify the tkinter module it would be possible. And that's what I wouldn't suggest

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Why not open a child window thus creating your own box with your own button like this:**

```
from tkinter import *
def messageWindow():
    win = Toplevel()
    win.title('warning')
    message = "This will delete stuff"
    Label(win, text=message).pack()
    Button(win, text='Delete', command=win.destroy).pack()
root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Bring up Message', command=messageWindow).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no way to change the text of the buttons for the built-in dialogs.

Your best option is to create your own dialog. It's not very hard to do, and it gives you absolute control over what is in the dialog widget.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that you cannot change names in Tkinter messageboxes, but you can make your own class of messagebox so that you can reuse it several times. The following code is the same as Tkinter messagebox, but it has args and kwargs as arguments. It is just for convenience.

I am also learning, so the code does not have flash and alarm.

```
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent=parent
        top=Toplevel(self.parent)
        top.geometry("400x200")
        top.transient(self.parent)

        top.title(args[0])
        f0=Frame(top)
        top.l1=Label(f0, text=args[1])
        top.l1.pack(pady=30)
        f0.pack()
        top.grab_set()
        top.f1=Frame(top)
        for key in kwargs:
            key=Button(top.f1, text=f"{kwargs[key]}")
            key.pack(side=LEFT)
        top.f1.pack()
```

The message box will look like this:
[image]