# How to create a MessageDialog with buttons diffrent than YES and No?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using [MessageDialog](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MessageDialog-class.html) to create a Message like:
[image]

```
dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self.GetParent(), 'Do you wish to Continue?', 'Warning!',wx.YES_NO| wx.ICON_WARNING)
```

I want it to be:

[image]

basicly all I need is to change the writing from `Yes` to something else.
How can I do that?

Comment: As [this answers tells you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242782/change-words-on-tkinter-messagebox-buttons), you cannot change the text on the buttons in default tkinter dialogs. So unfortunately, you'll need to make your own dialog...

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra im using wxpython not thinker.

Comment: Sorry misread, then [you can do it](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MessageDialog.html#MessageDialog.SetYesNoLabels): messageDialog.SetYesNoLabels("&Proceed", "&Don't proceed") (if I'm correct) :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the link to the answer in the OP comments is broken, I thought I would post an answer for posterity:

```
dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, f'Choose wisely', 'Choice Dialog', wx.YES_NO | wx.CANCEL | wx.CANCEL_DEFAULT | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)  # FYI, `ICON_QUESTION` doesn't work on Windows!
dialog.SetYesNoLabels('Label For Yes Button', 'Label For No Button')
answer = dialog.ShowModal()
dialog.Destroy()

# We changed the labels of the buttons on the Yes/No/Cancel dialog, but the IDs generated by pressing those
# buttons are the same as they would be if the button labels were not changed.
if answer == wx.ID_YES:
    # Do something for the "Yes" button press
    pass
elif answer == wx.ID_NO:
    # Do something for the "No" button press
    pass
else:
    # Do nothing for the "Cancel" button press
    return
```